# How to disable a button event on refresh using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to make a reward system where a user can login daily to receive rewards but if I click on the "Claim daily Reward", the button get's disabled which is fine but if I refresh the page, the button gets enabled.

This is the code

```js
const btn = document.querySelectorAll("#primary");

for (let i = 0; i < berries.length; i++) {
  btn[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
    btn.disabled = true
  })
}
```

```css
.berrycontainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
}

.berry {
  background: rgba(157, 236, 38, 0.938);
  border-radius: 0.4rem;
  margin-left: 2rem;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<main style="text-align: center;">
  <div class="berrycontainer">
    <div class="berry">
      <h1 class="berryh">20 berries</h1>
      <p class="day-paragraph">Day 1</p>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop">Claim Daily reward <i class="bi bi-clock-fill clock"
                    style="display: none;"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div class="berry">
      <h1 class="berryh">20 berries</h1>
      <p class="day-paragraph">Day 1</p>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop">Claim Daily reward <i class="bi bi-clock-fill clock"
                    style="display: none;"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div class="berry">
      <h1 class="berryh">20 berries</h1>
      <p class="day-paragraph">Day 1</p>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop">Claim Daily reward <i class="bi bi-clock-fill clock"
                    style="display: none;"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: You will have to store the information somewhere, either using Cookies, localstorage or server side.

Comment: As @ColdIV stated you need to some storage in order to get your work done but I don't think cookies, session, local Storage is a great idea because user can clear cookies, session and also local storage and get the reward after every reload what you can do is use an DB (database) store user info and then create some kind of variable or count which can +1 on every reward so even after reload user cannot receive reward again also set the duration of that variable 24 hours so user can again claim the award after a day.

Comment: as @ColdIV said, you need to store the state, but keep in mind it is extremely easy to enable a button from the client side, you need to check again from the server side if the reward was already received.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have a user, who is "logging in" somewhere, save the state of that reward/rewards in the place where you verify that login, I assume it is some database. Reset the state of "claimed" rewards on a daily basis there.